# Xcode 4 doesn't show the exception message

Tags: xcode

I had a xib file with an old outlet connected. That would crash and set a breakpoint on the line pushing the view controller with :

```
Catchpoint 2 (throw)Pending breakpoint 1 - "objc_exception_throw" resolved
```

Not very helpful, I remember in XCode 3 I had something like "an outlet is not connected"

How do I get that back ?

edit : if I check "automatically continue after evaluating actions", I get this message :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<OrderController 0x7942760> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key table.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x16e1052 0x2182d0a 0x16e0f11 0x4cb032 0x43cf7b 0x43ceeb 0x457d60 0x99991a 0x16e2e1a 0x164c821 0x99846e 0x83fe2c 0x8403a9 0x8405cb 0x840941 0x85247d 0x85266f 0x85293b 0x8533df 0x853986 0xcf67dbd 0x8535a4 0x3a3da 0x841fbf 0x8422d4 0x8425d7 0x842785 0x85c0a5 0x842730 0x78b5ea 0x16b59ce 0x164c670 0x16184f6 0x1617db4 0x1617ccb 0x18f7879 0x18f793e 0x77aa9b 0x276d 0x1fd5)
terminate called throwing an exceptionCurrent language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)
```

which is better than nother, but the breakpoint stops on main.m ! Here is the current setup of my breakpoint

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Mystery solved.  At least for me, hitting 'continue' a couple of times allowed the error to be printed to the console.

The issue (in this case) was having a couple of other custom breakpoints set (objc_exception_throw, -[NSException raise]).

Enabling "automatically continue after evaluating" for BOTH allowed the process to be killed without manual intervention, somewhere around which time the detailed error message was printed to the console.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple projects, make sure that the breakpoint is active for the correct project. I recommend using a Xcode 4 workspace in this case and assign the global exceptions breakpoint to the workspace. You can do that by right-clicking the breakpoint in the Breakpoints Navigator pane and select "Move Breakpoint to…"

Comment: I have one project, and and other projects the problem is the same. My breakpoint shows correctly under my project name. I uninstall devtools and did a fresh install. It breaks without message as usual, but if I hit continue, it will break on main and show me the error message. Quite counter intuitive (I need to remember the line where it breaks, then hit continue to see why)...

Comment: Yep, that's not the answer. Even with the exception breakpoint set, there is no english language description of the cause of the exception like there used to be in xcode 3